# Laravel application with multiple domains: overwrite app.name

Tags: php, laravel, dns, hosts

I have a working Laravel application with multiple domain names. 
In many templates and emails I use the config-appname:

```
{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
```

What is the best way to overwrite this config app name?

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
if($host == "domain1.com") {
    // new app name = "Domain1 Test"
} elseif($host == "domain2.com") {
    // new app name = "Domain2 Test"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not best practice to change config variables at runtime, see this similar topic https://laravel.io/forum/12-30-2015-how-to-change-the-configuration-in-runtime.

I would instead suggest switching out your calls from `{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}` to a helper or class file which has your domain identification logic. E.g. `{{ app_name() }}`.